# Installshield) how to prevent uninstalling when the program is running

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I'm using InstallShield 2019 Professional Edition and have a Basic MSI Project which includes some executable program.

In Basic MSI Project, I want to know how to prevent uninstalling program when the program is running.
Is there any option or install-script to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally your application should create a Mutex when it starts and release it when it shut's down.  Then you can write a custom action in the installer that looks for this mutex and blocks the uninstall if the mutex is present.

But honestly most people don't do this.  They just use the built-in behavior of FilesInUse.

Comment: Thanks. I opened a case last week in the Flexera community and they still didn't answer. But you gave me an answer in a day. This is very helpful to me. Thank you again. I'm a scuber diver too!